# TCP Client not receiving response on loopback

Tags: c#, response, tcpserver, loopback

I've got a TCP server up and running on localhost on vs2010 on windows 2k8.

When I connect the client on 127.0.0.1 using vs2010, the server gets the call, (I can see it 
 from debug) as the tcp server executes the command line protocol handler, but the client does 
 recieve the server response, which is the session key, but blocks at the client when reading 
 the respone stream.

When I use Telnet on loopback for the same port, sending the same command sequence, the 
 response, i.e. the session key, is received instantaneously.

Here is the client code:

```
EndPoint serverAddress = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 9121);
sing (Socket socket = new Socket(serverAddress.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp))
            {

                socket.Connect(serverAddress);

                var socketStream = new NetworkStream(socket);
                var reader = new StreamReader(socketStream, Encoding.ASCII, false);
                var writer = new StreamWriter(socketStream, Encoding.ASCII, 1024);

                string charSource = Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Replace("-", string.Empty)
                   + Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Replace("-", string.Empty)
                   + Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Replace("-", string.Empty);

                Random rd = new Random();


                int startPos = rd.Next(0, charSource.Length - 2);
                int endPos = rd.Next(startPos + 1, charSource.Length - 1);

                var currentMessage = charSource.Substring(startPos, endPos - startPos + 1);

                Console.WriteLine("Sent Command");

                writer.Write("HEAR {0} {1}", currentMessage.Length.ToString().PadLeft(4, '0'), currentMessage);
                writer.Flush();

                Console.WriteLine("Reading Command Results");
                var line = reader.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Received: " + line);
            }
```

Bob

Comment: We can never answer this. But we might if you show the relevant code.

Comment: You're missing a lot of information in the question. There could be a dozen variables contributing to your missing response. How can we guess?

Comment: Yes, thats what I figured. I'll post the client code.

Comment: Are you sending the cr and/or lf that ReadLine() is waiting for?

Comment: If you're going to *read* lines, you need to write lines too.

Comment: Not sending cr/lf intentionally. Command is of the format <Command> <DataLength> <Data> eg. HEAR 0004 jssa, HEAR is a CLP command for hearbeat. Tested the server with TCPBuilder, which is a socket tester, and the server worked fine. There is something missing in that daft code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make this work, please change Write with WriteLine as shown in the code below:

```
 Console.WriteLine("Sent Command");

 writer.WriteLine("HEAR {0} {1}", currentMessage.Length.ToString().PadLeft(4, '0'), currentMessage);
 writer.Flush();
```

Comment: Tried setting both to WriteLine. The client sits and waits.  Surely the flush writes the buffer stream to the channel.

Comment: I downloaded TCPIP builder and the server works fine. Do you recommend any example .NET TCP/P socket clients.

Comment: I created a client using TcpClient class, which worked fine. The server is working and send the correct session response.

Comment: Final solution was to add a newline into session response. After that the client worked fine, and discovered the test code was passing but was wrong.Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

[Enable network tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty48b824.aspx), so you can be sure that the data is comming. It probably is, so change your call to reader.Read and read until you find the end of the message.

Comment: Thanks for that. Hadn't seen it before.